# strange result when calling SHFileOperation to delete file after install MS office2003

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sdk

I use following code to delete a file. it wroks well.

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT FileOp;
ZeroMemory(&FileOp, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT));
FileOp.hwnd = m_hAppHandle;
FileOp.wFunc = FO_DELETE; //delete
FileOp.pFrom = szPath; 
FileOp.pTo = NULL; 
FileOp.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI;
FileOp.fAnyOperationsAborted = FALSE; 
FileOp.hNameMappings = NULL; 
FileOp.lpszProgressTitle = NULL;  

SHFileOperation(&FileOp);
```

But rcently I found a strang thing, the reproduction step as follow:
1. install win2000
2. install MS office2003

the at the first time (and only the first time) I call  "SHFileOperation" function to delete a file. then a system warnning message box show

"Windows cannot create a shortcut here. Do you want the shortcut to be placed on the desktop instead? 
"

no matter I choose "OK" or "NO" button to close the warnning message box. then, such warnning message box  never show again, i.e. , after I close the warnning message box, I can call "SHFileOperation" function  to delete a file without such system warnning message.

It is truely magic, It just happens one time.

Any guy kown some related information? Thanks.

Comment: I have removed the MFC tag, as this question uses plain win32 API calls, no MFC is involved.

Comment: I debug my app, and I found this strange phenomenon is caused by my mistake.

at my app, the path name assgined to FileOp.pFrom  ("FileOp.pFrom = szPath;"  ) is "C:xxx\yy\\zz" , not "c:xxx\yy\zz". the duplicate "\" charchater make this strange behavior appers.

however, I still confused why this just happen after I installed MS office, and It just happens one time.

Answer (score 3):

The `pFrom` member of `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` is a list of null-terminated strings and should end with a double null.  It looks like `szPath` is a single null-terminated string with only one path in it.  This will mean`SHFileOperation` will read beyond your intended end of `pFrom`.

MSDN Library for `SHFILEOPSTRUCT`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795%28VS.85%29.aspx

Blog article about this: [Don't forget to double-null-terminate those strings you pass to SHFileOperation](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/18/9965469.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you remind. I have already use double null and the function works well except the first time after I installed MS Office.
see
"
THCAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
memset(&szPath, 0, sizeof(szPath[0])*MAX_PATH);
"

Comment: *"should end with a double null"* - That's technically not correct. String lists are commonly modeled as zero-terminated strings, terminated by an empty string. Which means that an empty list will *not* end with a double null, but rather a single one.