# C++ MFC SHFILEOPSTRUCT FO_DELETE does not work

Tags: c++, mfc

My problem is that the file is not deleted.

In VS2010, the code works (file is deleted).

It no longer works in VS2019 or VS2022.

I commented out the flags (`FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI...`) for testing, then the Windows dialog appears that admin rights are required to delete.

Of course, I don't want to display a dialog in my program, I just want to silently delete a file.

```cpp
CString PfadAltesLogoLoeschen = "C:\\ROBL - PC - WARE\\RechnungFixxx\\Data\\Logo.bmp";

PfadAltesLogoLoeschen += '\0';
        
SHFILEOPSTRUCT shFile1;
ZeroMemory(&shFile1, sizeof(shFile1));
shFile1.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
shFile1.pFrom = PfadAltesLogoLoeschen;
shFile1.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
SHFileOperation(&shFile1);
```

Comment: Your code is missing quotation marks in the first line.

Comment: First of all please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. The less other unrelated problems and errors there are, the better. A perfect one would be possible for us to just copy-paste without any modifications and replicate the exact problem you ask about and nothing more.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the proper permissions to delete the file?  Edit: ***I commented out the flags (FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI...) for testing, then the Windows dialog appears that admin rights are required to delete.*** So you are trying to avoid UAC?

Comment: Then add some error checking in your code. Check what [`SHFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa) returns.

Comment: Also, [the `pFrom` needs to be double-null terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317009).

Comment: The issue is unrelated to the version of Visual Studio you are using to compile the code. The difference is in the environment that's executing the binary.

Comment: @ray Isn't `pFrom` double-null terminated? There's an explicit `'\0'` appended to the `CString` instance constructed from a NUL terminated string literal.

Comment: "*I just want to silently delete a file*" - then why are you using `SHFileOperation()` at all? You should use [`DeleteFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) instead: `CString PfadAltesLogoLoeschen = "..."; DeleteFile(PfadAltesLogoLoeschen);`

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, I missed that part. So the double null termination is not an issue in this case. (CString is not something I work with so I'm unfamiliar with its finer points.)